# Which level player is Parzival in Ready Player One?

Tags: plot-explanation, ready-player-one

I saw the movie [*Ready Player One*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready_Player_One_(film)), and find out that one player gets level up going through the game and you can get special artifacts according to your level.

I was wondering which level player is Parzival at the start of the movie? Is it mentioned anywhere in the movie?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not stated in the movie and, in that medium, the "levels" aren't explicit being more related to the amount of coin and artefacts held.

In the *novel* however, Parzival starts the story on..

## Level 3

> Over the past few years, the Basement had become a highly exclusive hangout for elite gunters. Aech granted access only to people he deemed worthy, so being invited to hang out in the Basement was a big honor, **especially for a third-level nobody like me**.
>
> <sup>*Ready Player One* - Ernest Cline</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In the book, Parzival starts out low level because he lacks the cash to be able to afford to travel to planets where he can actually play the game.  (Travel to his school planet is free.)  He mentions getting lifts from people occasionally to kill low level rats and such, but he hasn't done that much.

In the book, this is a bit of a problem, because the first dungeon is a D&D dungeon...but apparently his knowledge of the layout of the dungeon allows him to get through it safely.  After passing the first gate, he wins a prize consisting of lots of in-game money, which he uses to grind to being top level...but I don't think that being leveled helps him much, if at all.

Comment: In the books he does the grind to Max level at one point, it also leads to the stronger connection with some of the other characters in the books since they do some outside quests together.  Also probably helps in the PvP including the final battle.